# R Error in manova(classification ~ ., data) : need multiple responses

Tags: r, manova

I'm trying to get a MANOVA running to get Wilk's Lambda from the summary but I get a constant "need multiple responses" error. Looking at past answers I figured that one of the variables might be missing from the data frame but it doesn't seem like it..

here's head(data):

```
head(data)
      ror penalty  last30 classification
1 4.97782 1.35074 4.83647           Good
2 4.65229 1.17034 4.99381           Good
3 4.91005 2.33616  4.8811           Good
4 4.85295 1.90597 4.82852           Good
5 4.79894 1.67042 4.81287           Good
6 4.50941 0.96402 4.88748           Good
```

head(classification)

```
 head(classification)
[1] "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good" "Good"
```

code:

```
raw <- read.csv("~/Downloads/rp_r/draft_b.csv")
params <- cbind(raw$scaled, raw$penalty_scaled, raw$scale)
    classification <- c(1:length(raw$final_rank)) 
cutoff = 20
  for (i in 1:length(classification)) {
    if (raw$final_rank[i] < cutoff) {
      classification[i] <- "Bad"
    } else {
      classification[i] <- "Good"
    }
  }  

data=data.frame(cbind(ror=params[,1], penalty=params[,2], last30=params[,3], classification))
m <- manova(classification ~., data)  
  summary(m,test="Wilks")
```

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Why are you trying to apply `manova`, which is explicitly for multiple responses, to a variable that represents just a *single* response?

Comment: I want to get Wilks lambda for a priorly done LDA on the same data set and from what I have read so far there is no other easy way to get Wilk's Lambda in R for LDA - and the manova generated wilk's works just as good as a measure for that? I'd be happy if you would correct me!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've figured it out by now, but the reason you're receiving that error is because your X and Y are backwards in your model. See the last two lines of your code--it should read:

```
m <- manova(. ~ classification, data)
```

, instead of the other way around.

If this doesn't work, try putting cbind directly in your dataset, as in:

```
m <- manova(cbind(ror=params[,1], penalty=params[,2], last30=params[,3] ~ classification, data)
```

Comment: But in case where you have lot of columns and you don't want to use cbind ?